# Iterating through nested array and extracting data

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I have just merged two arrays containing JSON objects into each other. The result is a pretty complex array and I need to extract a few information out of this array.

Here is a picture of the array of what it looks like right now (Firebug Screenshot) (just the first entry in the array):

[image]

The "answer" array contains my answers (answervalue and date). The attribute "itemindex" is something like a reference to the original question.

So what I basically want to do is:
Iterate through my answer array and check the "itemindex" to get the original question. The question is stored in the "elements" array on position itemindex inside the "body" attribute.
After somehow receiving what is written inside each "body", I want to create a new array of JSON objects that has the following structure: (I know that THIS exactly does not work, I just want to make my idea more clear)

```
newArray = [{question: elements[itemindex].body, answer: answer.answervalue, date: answer.answered_at}]
```

How can I iterate through my complete array above and put everything into the new form?
I have already a knot in my brain and I hope there is someone who can help me on this on!

Comment: Adding the JS for that array to your question would be a lot more useful than a screenshot.

Comment: You mean how I created the Array? Or the JSON format?

Comment: Stringify the data and add that first element so we can properly see the object structure without squinting at a screenshot.

Comment: You will get an answer very quickly if you show a Javascript data declaration (in text of Javascript code, not in a screenshot) for what the original form of the data is and then show a new Javascript data declaration for what you want the new form of the data to be.  That would make your question 100% clear and simple to understand what you want.

Comment: I would like to upload code, but I don't know what you people really want. All the routes, services, controller and stuff? My array is declared through a merge of two other arrays...-.-

Comment: @chakuze Take your data (whats in the screenshot) and paste it in your question as text, then people can manipulate it more easily.  Then tell us what you'd like the expected output to be, and we can help you get there.